# Excel: Row value to columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have the following table:

```
Name        Group
John        2A
John        1B
Barry       2A
Ron         1B
Ron         2A
Ron         2C
```

I wanted to know if there was any utility in Excel where I can separate the **group** column into a new column of for each instance.

Expected Result

```
Name        Group1      Group2      Group3
John        2A          1B
Barry       2A
Ron         1B          2A          2C
```

In this example I know that the max Groups are 3. So I made Group1, Group2, and Group3 columns.

Comment: Personally, I would keep the data as is.  That flat file sort of format is very easy for Excel to work with, and splitting it out makes the data difficult to work with.  For example, if you need to see who is in which groups, you can get that information simply by using filters.

Comment: I need to split the repeating names into group columns in order.

Comment: Alright, do you want to preserve the original table or convert it to the new format?  Also, would you prefer a formula solution or a VBA solution?

Comment: I want to convert it into a new format. I would prefer a formula or other Excel utility. I know a bit of VBA, just not that much with Excel, mostly in Access.

Comment: Have you tried a Pivot Table?  It won't display the data as you've asked, but it'd get pretty close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 2C is in B7 and working on a copy, put:

`=IF(COLUMN()<COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)+2,IF($A2=$A3,INDIRECT("$B"&ROW()+COLUMN()-2),""),"")`

in C2 and copy across  (to ColumnZ or further if you wish but to ColumnD would be sufficient for your example) and down to suit.

In an available column put:

`=OR(A1=A3,A1=A2)`

and copy down to suit.

Fix the formulae (Select/Copy/Paste Special Values), filter on the 'available' column to select TRUE, delete selected rows and delete the 'available' column. Add column labels to suit.

Comment: I put the formula in C2 and copied across, but it is blank.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Had some extra text in the A column fields and they weren't matching. I like this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution that will put the converted table on a new sheet:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim NameCell As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim DataIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long

    Set wsData = ActiveSheet
    Set wsDest = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , wsDest.Range("A1"), True
    wsData.Range("B1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , wsDest.Range("B1"), True
    wsDest.Range("B2", wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Copy
    wsDest.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    With wsDest.Range("A1", wsDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        With .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1)
            .Value = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("Index(""Group""&Row(1:" & .Columns.Count & "),)"))
        End With
    End With
    ReDim arrData(1 To wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1 To wsDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1)
    For Each NameCell In wsDest.Range("A2", wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        DataIndex = DataIndex + 1
        Set rngFound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(NameCell.Text, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            cIndex = 0
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                cIndex = cIndex + 1
                arrData(DataIndex, cIndex) = wsData.Cells(rngFound.Row, "B").Text
                Set rngFound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(NameCell.Text, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    Next NameCell

    If DataIndex > 0 Then wsDest.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData

    Set wsData = Nothing
    Set wsDest = Nothing
    Set NameCell = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Erase arrData

End Sub
```

How to use a macro:

1. Make a copy of the workbook the macro will be run on

   - Always run new code on a workbook copy, just in case the code doesn't run smoothly
   - This is especially true of any code that deletes anything
2. In the copied workbook, press ALT+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor
3. Insert | Module Copy the provided code and paste into the module
4. Close the Visual Basic Editor
5. In Excel, press ALT+F8 to bring up the list of available macros to run
6. Double-click the desired macro (I named this one tgr)